# How to temporarily hide hydrogen atoms in Molden?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I am visualizing some molecules with Molden. Is there a way to hide hydrogens, without deleting the hydrogen entries from the structure file?

Comment: I don't see any such feature in the [manual](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/keywords.html) or [command-line flags](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/command.html). Offhand, I'd say no.

Comment: @Geoff It has and had this option for a while at least. I checked the history and it came sometime in Molden3.2 (added a button "H" to undisplay hydrogens).

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are not using an ancient version of Molden, this should be no problem. (The oldest one I found in my software archive was Moleden5.1 from [January 2014](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/HISTORY) and it already contains this feature.)

In the Molden control window there is a button with an italic *H*. This will open a menu with "Excl. All Hydrogens", "Excl. H except H-bond", "(Re)calculate H-bond", "H-bond parameters", and "Opt. H positions". I'll leave it to you to play around with it, below you find a small animation of the first two modes for the [base pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_pair) GC.

[image: screen capture of different display modes]

And because it is a little bit too tiny in the gif, here is a crop of the Molden control window.

[image: screenshot of Molden control window]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such an option in molden. Take another (free) program (*f.e.* molekel)

Comment: This is false (and likely was false at the time of answering), see my answer for how to do it.